# How to fetch populated associated models in CakePHP when calling read()

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have the following Models:

```
class Site extends AppModel {
    public $name = "Site";
    public $useTable = "site";
    public $primaryKey = "id";
    public $displayField = 'name';

    public $hasMany = array('Item' => array('foreignKey' => 'siteId'));

    public function canView($userId, $isAdmin = false) {
        if($isAdmin) { return true; }
        return array_key_exists($this->id, $allowedSites)!==false;
    }
}
```

and

```
class Item extends AppModel {
    public $name = "Item";
    public $useTable = "item";
    public $primaryKey = "id";
    public $displayField = 'name';
    public $belongsTo = array('Site' => array('foreignKey' => 'siteId'));

     public function canView($userId, $isAdmin = false) {
        // My problem appears to be the next line:
        return $this->Site->canView($userId, $isAdmin);
    }

 }
```

In my controller I am doing something like this:

```
$result = $this->Item->read(null, $this->request->id);

// Verify permissions
if(!$this->Item->canView($this->Session->read('userId'), $this->Session->read('isAdmin'))) {
    $this->httpCodes(403);
    die('Permission denied.');
}
```

I notice that in `Item->canView()` `$this->data['Site']` is populated with the column data from the site table. But it is merely an array and not an object.

On the other hand `$this->Site` is a Site object, but it has not been populated with the column data from the site table like `$this->data`.

What is the proper way to have CakePHP get the associated model as the object (so I can call methods on it) and containing the data? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"...and sets the current model data (Model::$data) with the record found." from http://api13.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelread

Comment: I could just call `$this->Site->read()` using the foreignKey id from `$this->data` but that would cause an extra database query to be performed, right? This seems unnecessary since I already have the data in `$this->data['Site']`, it just isn't assigned to the object. I could perhaps also just set the `$data` member of `$this->Site` since I already have the data, but that seems like a hackish way of dealing with it.